# Ionic 3 not rebuilding on file change

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, iconic

Am starting a new project on ionic version 3.20

Every time I `update` a file, the web page isn't `refreshing/rebuilding`, where it suppose to live reload on "`localhost:8100`"...

So am stopping ionic and run "`ionic serve`" again on every update.

Although when i refresh the web page `(localhost:8100)` the page is reloading till infinity.

I have `uninstall` `cordova` and ionic, and still same issue comes.

Any solutions please.?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
npm run ionic:serve
```

it will work